# How to insert each product with its id, qty, title, price, type from below array to DB using PHP?

Tags: multidimensional-array, associative-array

How to insert each product with its id, qty, title, price, type from below multidimensional associative array(which comes from JSON) to MySQL Database using PHP? I have tried foreach loop but not allowing to echo or insert it, gives an error. I want to insert values into database i.e to insert each product with its id, qty, title, price, type

```
    $array = Array
    (
    [page] => 1
    [current] => 100
    [count] => 5
    [pageCount] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [qty] => 30
                            [title] => abc
                            [price] => 200
                            [type] => men
                        )
```

`[info] => Array
                    (
                        [brand] => xyz
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12
                        [qty] => 50
                        [title] => dfg
                        [price] => 300
                        [type] => girl
                    )

                [info] => Array
                    (
                        [brand] => jkl
                    )

            )
    )
)
</pre>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the correct solution. Please find code below.

```
$i=0;
foreach($array['data'][$i] as $a){
     $id = $a['product']['id'];
     $qty = $a['product']['qty'];
     $title = $a['product']['title'];
     $price = $a['product']['price'];
     $type = $a['product']['type'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (id,qty,title,price,type) values ('$id','$qty','$title','$price','$type')";

     $i++;                  
}
$i=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried something like this?

foreach ($array["data"] as $item) {

echo $item["product"]["id"]; 
echo $item["product"]["qty"];
// and so on for each field
echo $item["info"]["brand"];

}

Else can you be more specific on the format that you need printed?
```

Comment: Not Working, it's multidimensional associative array

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/54c0887351b887496b0008b9

Comment: Already tried, but not working, so, finally posted question here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert into a database, iterate over your array, break out the fields manually and use code like below to insert into a database

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Why specifically echo? Why not print_r? That's what I dn't understand. And if you echo, what does that have to do with a database?

Comment: print_r will print entire array, will not insert each value one by one for an above-stated array. If you can then plz provide...

Comment: Normally echo prints to console. What I'm confused about is whether you want to echo to the console, or insert into a database.